Lower bound for a commutator trace
I have this Hilbert space of square-integrable complex-valued functions on a square, $\mathbb{L}^2([0,1]^2)$. And let $M_x$, $M_y$, and $M_{x+y} = M_x+M_y$ be the operators of multiplication by the coordinates and by their sum.
I also have a sequence, say, $(n^{-1/2})_{n=1}^\infty$. Or some $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $\sup(n^{1/2}a_n) \le 1$, you choose.
And I'd like a (compact) operator $A$ with this sequence as its singular values (multiplicity 1, or bounded multiplicity with a known bound), so that for $|Tr([A,M_{x+y}])|$ (the bigger the better, or at least positive), if we don't explicitly know the value, we have an explicit (positive) lower bound. Here $Tr$ is the usual operator trace.
Is this too much to ask? Replacing $A$ with $A_1$ and $A_2$ and replacing $[A,M_{x+y}]$ with $[A_1,M_x]+[A_2,M_y]$ is acceptable, too.
I'm thinking with Pincus' $g$-function, the double operator integral, and all that, one might come up with something. What do you think? Somebody must've looked at this type of problem before, no?
